# Map Markers Side Bar Not Updating SideBar Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The following code is working great.  It imports XML data from database, numbers and plots map markers, loads the sidebar.

I'm filtering my results by featured category.  The function launches on clicking a radio button in the html.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="featuredbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'featured')" />
```

This part works great. I toggle the radio button and the appropriate map markers are toggled on and off.

My problem is that the sidebar doesn't update accordingly. I got this far working from the following example: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html

Here is all my code:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap_markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

      google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
      var map = null;
      var markers = [];
      var infoWindow;
      var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$gmap_center_point?>);


<!-- This function creates marker and populates the infobubble -->
      function createMarker(latlng, name, address, profile_link, number_count, distance, featured, coupons, youtube_activate, additional_photo, logo, account_priority) {

      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/><font color=\"red\">Approx. " + distance.toFixed(1) + " miles away</font><br/>"
<!--      html += '<a class="menu" href="javascript: map.setZoom('+zoom+');">Zoom To</a>';  --> 
<!--      html += ' <a class="menu" href="javascript:function togglestreetview();">Street View</a>';  -->
<!--      html += ' | ';   -->
      html += ' <a  class="menu" href="javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('+latlng.toUrlValue(6)+')); map.setZoom(parseInt(map.getZoom())+2);">Zoom In</a>';
      html += ' | '; 
      html += ' <a  class="menu" href="javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('+latlng.toUrlValue(6)+')); map.setZoom(parseInt(map.getZoom())-2);">Out </a>';
      html += '<br/>'+ profile_link ; 


      var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

<!-- Label Options Reference http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/examples/-->
            labelContent: number_count,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 36),
            labelClass: "gmap_labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelInBackground: false
            });
              marker.featured = featured;
              marker.coupon = coupons;
              marker.youtube = youtube_activate;
              marker.photo = additional_photo;
              marker.name = name;

              markers.push(marker);         

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infoWindow.setContent(html);
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });

   }



      // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
      function show_type(option) {
        for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
          if (markers[i].featured == 1){
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
          }

        }
       // == check the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(option+"box").checked = true;

      }

      // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
      function hide_type(option) {
        for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
          if (markers[i].featured == 1) {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
          // == clear the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(option+"box").checked = false;
        // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
        infoWindow.close( );

      }

     // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
      function boxclick(box,option) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show_type(option);

        } else {
          hide_type(option);

        }
        // == rebuild the side bar
        createSidebarEntry(name, address, distance, num, featured, coupons, youtube_activate, additional_photo, logo, profile_link, number_count);

      }

<!-- This function . . . -->
      function createSidebarEntry(name, address, distance, num, featured, coupons, youtube_activate, additional_photo, logo, profile_link, number_count) {

      var html = ' ';


      html += '<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"5\"><tr><td width=\"20px\" valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">'
      html += '<span style=\"padding: 3px; background-color: #F30; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"> '+ number_count + ' </td>'
      html += '<td >'
      if (featured==1){ 
                    html += '<img src=\"images/_icon_banner_featured.png\" width=\"180\" height=\"19\" /><br/>'
                    }else{ }
      html += '<b>' + name + '</b><br/>'
      html += '<font color=\"red\" size=\"1\" >Approx. ' + distance.toFixed(1) + ' miles away.</font><br/>'
      html += address + '<br/>'
      if (coupons==1 || youtube_activate==1 || additional_photo==1){
                             html +='<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr>'
                             if (coupons ==1){
                                 html +='<td align=\"left\"><img src=\"images/_icon_results_coupons.png\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\" alt=\"Coupons Available\" />' 
                             }else{ }
                             if (youtube_activate ==1){
                                 html +='<img src=\"images/_icon_results_youtube.png\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\" alt=\"Videos Available\"/>' 
                             }else{ }
                             if (additional_photo==1){
                                 html +='<img src=\"images/_icon_results_photo.png\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\" alt=\"Photos Available\"/>' 
                             }else{ }
                             html +='</td></tr></table>'
                    }else{ }

      html +='</td></tr></table>';

      var div = document.createElement("div");       
      div.value = num;
      div.innerHTML = html;
      div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      div.style.marginBottom = '5px'; 
      sidebar.appendChild(div);


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'click', function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[num], 'click');
      });
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function() {
      div.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
      });
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function() {
      div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
      });


    return div ;

    }



<!-- This function does the Search based on AddressInput -->
     function searchLocations() {
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
        alert(address + ' not found');
        }
     });
   }


<!-- FUNCTION -->
     function clearLocations() {
     infoWindow.close();
     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     markers[i].setMap(null);
     }
     markers.length = 0;
  }


<!-- This function queries the Processing File based on criteria set... radius... search term.  etc.-->
     function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations();

     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchrequest = document.getElementById('search').value;

     var searchUrl = 'search_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius + '&searchrequest=' + searchrequest;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
     var xml = parseXml(data);
     var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
     var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
     sidebar.innerHTML = '';

         if (markerNodes.length == 0) {
             sidebar.innerHTML = 'No results found.';
             map.setZoom(6);
             map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$gmap_center_point?>));
             return;
             }

             var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

             for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {

    <!-- GRAB THE VARIABLES ATTRIBUTES FROM PROCESSING FILE AND ASSIGN VARS TO EACH RESULT RETURNED -->
             var v_id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("v_id");
             var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
             var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
             var profile_link = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("profile_link");
             var featured = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("featured");            
             var coupons = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("coupons");
             var youtube_activate = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("youtube_activate");     
             var additional_photo = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("additional_photo");
             var category_id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("category_id");
             var category_name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("category_name");
             var sub_cat_id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("sub_cat_id");
             var sub_cat_name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("sub_cat_name");
             var account_priority = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("account_priority");
             var logo = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("logo");
             var number_count = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("number_count");
             var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));


                  createSidebarEntry(name, address, distance, i, featured, coupons, youtube_activate, additional_photo, logo, profile_link, number_count, account_priority);

                  createMarker(latlng, name, address, profile_link, number_count, distance, featured, coupons, youtube_activate, additional_photo, logo, account_priority);

                  bounds.extend(latlng);
                  }
                // == show or hide the categories initially ==
                show_type("featured");

                // == create the initial sidebar ==   


                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                filtering.style.visibility = "visible";
         });


  }


      <!-- FUNCTION -->
      function load() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$gmap_center_point?>),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
            });

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

              <!-- STICK A CUSTOM PIN IN CENTER LOCATION -->
              var center_marker=new google.maps.Marker({
              map:map,
              position:myCenter,
              clickable: true,
              icon:'/images/GHV_map_marker.png'
              });
                    center_marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'My Location'
                    });
                            google.maps.event.addListener(center_marker, 'click', function() {
                            center_marker.info.open(map, center_marker);
                            });  

                                  center_marker.setMap(map);

                                  <!-- THIS FUNCTION LAUNCHES ONLY AFTER FULL PAGE IS LOADED AND RUNS SEARCHLOCATIONS WITH SET VARIABLE -->
                                  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {

                                  searchLocations(<?=$gmap_center_point?>);

                                  });

    }



<!-- This function . . . -->
      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }


<!-- This function . . . -->
        function parseXml(str) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
        } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
        }
    }



<!-- This function . . . -->
    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: using my code here.  the sidebar updates?

Comment: I've removed a dead demo link from this question, and given that the supplied code is rather long, and given it has not attracted any attention for 2.5 years, I think this is safe to close.

Comment: Think this is a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17518531/472495) anyway.